# d3.js - multiple charts on same page from different parts of same JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've searched far and wide and I wasn't able to figure out what's wrong with my code. Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
var data={
    "by_date":[
        {"date":"2014-01-01", "count":10},
        {"date":"2014-02-01", "count":20},
        {"date":"2014-03-01", "count":30},
        {"date":"2014-04-01", "count":15},
        {"date":"2014-05-01", "count":20}
    ],
    "by_location": {
        "name":"World","children":[
            {
                "name":"United States", "children":[{"name":"New York", "children":[{"name":"Albany","count":5}, {"name":"NYC","count":5}]}]
            },
            {
                "name":"Canda", "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"Alberta", "children":[{"name":"Edmonton","count":5},{"name":"Calgary","count":5}]
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"British Columbia", "children":[{"name":"Victoria","count":2},{"name":"Vancouver","count":8}]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"China", "children":[{"name":"Beijing","count":30}]
            },
            {
                "name":"India", "children":[{"name":"Bangalore","count":15}]
            },
            {
                "name":"Germany", "children":[{"name":"Frankfurt","count":20}]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I want to display a line chart using data from `data.by_date` and a zoomable circlepack from `data.by_location` on the same HTML page. I have two Javascript functions `by_date`, which creates a line chart, and `by_location`, which creates a circlepack, and they both have the exact same code as  Mike Bostock's line chart and zoomable circlepack examples and I call them as follows:

```
by_date(data.by_date);
by_location(data.by_location); // Creates circlepack, but zoom doesn't work.
```

The problem is that while both the line chart and the circlepack are created and displayed on the page, the zoom functionality doesn't work on the circlepack. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
```

However, if I don't call `by_date` and only call `by_location`, it works perfectly fine.

```
//by_date(data.by_date);
by_location(data.by_location); // Zoom works great now!
```

Since `by_date` uses only `data.by_date`, and doesn't even touch `data.by_location`, why would commenting it out somehow make `by_location` work okay?

Here are fiddles demonstrating the issue:

Both line and circlepack (circlepack doesn't zoom): http://jsfiddle.net/xk5aqf8t/6/

Line chart function `by_date` commented (zoom works fine): http://jsfiddle.net/38sayeqa/

Note that the *only* difference between the two fiddles is the commented call to `by_date`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that in your zoom transition you're selecting all `text` elements in the document, including the line chart where elements' bound data doesn't have any `parent` property (hence the error message).

The fix is easy. Just constrain your transition selection to the current chart. In your case you already have a selection of text elements, you can simply reuse it as demonstrated below:

```
// Let's keep our initial selection in the text variable:
var text = svg.selectAll('text').data(nodes);
text.enter()... // the entering selection is a subselection, so we keep it separate

// Create a new transition on the existing selection of text nodes
var transition = text.transition().duration(...); // the transition will reuse `text` selection
transition.filter(...); // don't subselect anything here
```

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cqb3uw8/).

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I completely missed the fact that `transition.selectAll("text")` was selecting *all* text nodes in the document. Thanks very much!